# minGW CPP G++ Proper Command to Compile

Tags: c++, g++

I installed the following:
      MINGW32_NT-6.1  i686 Msys

I am working with the command line.
Wrote the "typical" HelloWorld.cpp  program.

IF I compile with:  `cpp HelloWorld.cpp -o HelloWorld.exe`      COMPILE is good. (18k)
BUT execution fails:  16 bit MS-DOS Subsystem.  NTVDM CPU error

IF I compile with: `g++ HelloWorld.cpp -o HelloWorld.exe`       COMPILE is good.  (48k)
Execution is good.

I cannot determine the BEST way to execute the compile and what the difference is between the methods.  Any suggestions?   or  good references?
THANKS.

Comment: You *cannot determine the BEST way to execute the compile* when one of the options compiles and runs and the other doesn't? Given the choices...

Answer (score 3):

"cpp" is the "C PreProcessor", not the compiler. So you're just getting something strange in HelloWorld.exe

Execute the "type HelloWorld.exe" and see what it gives. It shouldn't even be a binary file - just a long text file with all the "#includes" and "#defines" replaced.

To your question - the second way is "right", because you actually invoke the compiler/linker and produce a valid executable. The first "way" is a valid command, but it has almost nothing to do with compilation and linking.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance!!  Your simple yet informative message has resolved ALL my issues and the app is running as expected!!

Comment: Glad to help. There are always such troubles when you start using some new tool. By the way, if the answer is good you can _accept_ it with the button below the votes.